# How do I use BooleanJunction with Hibernate Search

Tags: jquery, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I trying to build this query with hibernate search, I could not succeed.

```
Select * from message where (sender.id = "1" AND message.status = "sent") OR (recipient.id = "1" AND message.status = "new") OR (recipient.id = "1" AND message.status = "seen")
```

how can I do it with lucene?

I stuck here

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(getPersistentClass()).get();

    BooleanQuery bquery = new BooleanQuery();

    Query q1 = qb.keyword().onField("sender.id").matching(user.getId()).createQuery();
    Query q2 = qb.keyword().onField("status").matching(Message.Status.SENT).createQuery();
    BooleanJunction must1 = qb.bool();
    must1.must(q1);
    must1.must(q2);

    Query q3 = qb.keyword().onField("recipient.id").matching(user.getId()).createQuery();
    Query q4 = qb.keyword().onField("status").matching(Message.Status.NEW).createQuery();

    BooleanJunction must2 = qb.bool();
    must2.must(q3);
    must2.must(q4);

    Query q5 = qb.keyword().onField("recipient.id").matching(user.getId()).createQuery();
    Query q6 = qb.keyword().onField("status").matching(Message.Status.SEEN).createQuery();

    BooleanJunction must3 = qb.bool();
    must3.must(q5);
    must3.must(q6);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = qb.bool()
    .should(must1.createQuery())
    .should(must2.createQuery())
    .should(must3.createQuery())
    .createQuery();
```